# Cassandra structure for comments and comment replies tables

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, cassandra

I am trying to create a website where user can write text post , other user can comment on post and even other user can reply over comment. 
New to Cassandra , Please help in creating  data model for this.

existing data model is below

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id uuid,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    email text,
    created_date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE user_credentials (
    email text,
    password text,
    userid uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
);


CREATE TABLE user_posts (
  user_id uuid,
  post_id timeuuid, 
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id) )
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_id DESC);


Create TABLE comment_by_post (
  post_id timeuuid,
  user_id uuid,
  comment_date timestamp, 
  context text ,
  primary key (post_id,user_id,comment_date))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (comment_date);


Create Table comment_by_user (
  post_id timeuuid ,
  user_id uuid,
  comment_date timestamp ,
  content text,
  primary key (user_id,post_id,comment_date))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (comment_date);
```

Comment: I think it is not a question of cassandra modeling or mysql etc. First thing first You have to think about what is a user in your application, what is a post or a comment in your application?

Comment: its a simple application where user can write post "text" and other user can comment over the post .@Novy

Comment: You do not really need a user credential table this information could be stored in the user. And then with spring data you could use projection to show only some part of the user repository. What is the problem with your data model? @shubham bhindwal

Comment: I am having issue in creating comment system where user can reply to other comments over the post @Novy

Answer (score 0):

i am a mongodb developer not a cassandraDB developer but i can help you with some data models, i will follow json syntaxe for modeling : {attr : value}

for the comment/reply there are two ways :

1. embade replies in the comment collection (table in cassandra) like this :

   ```
   {


       commentID : 1,
       userID : 12,
       postID : 15,
       text : "some comment",
       /*other fields*/
       replies : [

           {
               replyID : 1,
               userID : 16,
               text : "some reply"
           },
           {
               replyID : 2,
               userID : 35,
               text : "some reply"
           },
       ]
    }
   ```
2. create separate collection (table) for each comments replies :

comments :

```
{
    commentID : 1,
    userID : 12,
    postID : 15,
    text : "some comment",
    /*other fields*/
}
```

replies :

```
{
    replyID : 1,
    replyTo : 1,
    userID : 16,
    text : "some reply"
}

{
    replyID : 2,
    replyTo : 1,
    userID : 35,
    text : "some reply"
}
```